# When to use atomic operations while programming?

Tags: c, multithreading, architecture, operating-system

I knew that cpu provides atomic instructions to atomically access a specified memory address. I'm curious about when should we use atomic instructions. More extractly, some experts told me that "we should use atomic when more than two threads access the shared variable". My question is that what if I have a reading thread with a writing thread? For example, I have non-atomic code snippets below:

```c
#define READY 1
#define NOTREADY 0

int flag;
int msg;

// thread 1
void reader() {
    while (flag == NOTREADY) ;  // not-atomic operation

    process(msg);

    flag = NOTREADY;
}

// thread 2
void writer() {
    while (1) {
        while (flag == READY) ;
        msg = send_msg();
        flag = READY;  // not-atomic operation
    }
}
```

In this example, thread 1 enters spinloop until `flag` is `NOTREADY`, while thread 2 will `send_msg` and set `flag` to `READY`. What if I don't make accesses to `flag` atomic operation? Would these codes run well?

I tried to run code below and the result is ok.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define READY 1
#define NOTREADY 0

int msg, flag = NOTREADY, cnt = 0;

void process(int msg) {
  printf("Processing msg: %d\n", msg);
}

void *reader() {
  while (cnt < 200000) {
    while (flag == NOTREADY) ;

    process(msg);

    flag = NOTREADY;
  }
}

int send_msg() {
  cnt ++;
  printf("Sending msg: %d\n", cnt);
  return cnt;
}

void *writer() {
  while (cnt < 200000) {
    while (flag == READY) ;

    msg = send_msg();

    flag = READY;
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t r_id, w_id;
  pthread_create(&r_id, NULL, reader, NULL);
  pthread_create(&w_id, NULL, writer, NULL);

  pthread_join(r_id, NULL);
  pthread_join(w_id, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

So could we omit atomic operation when the program has only one thread for reading and one thread for writing to the shared variable? If we can't, why not?

Comment: Even in so called "lock-free" designs, there's a potential real-time issue when a value is supposed to be updated at a regular interval. A sudden context switch happening around the time when the value is used could either lead to the old value getting used 2 cycles in a row, or an old value never getting used but replaced with a new one. This is mostly a thing in actual real-time systems though, not in *nix or similar desktop OS, where all timing is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks! I have no experience in real time operating systems. I will see it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, omitting atomic operations is working, but it is not guaranteed to always work.

The reason is that the compiler and CPU are optimizing your code in a way that happens to work in this simple example, but it is not guaranteed behavior.

The potential issues are:

Instruction reordering - The CPU may reorder the instructions within a thread in a way that affects the other thread. For example, it may move the flag = READY statement before the msg = send_msg() statement. If this happens, the reader thread could see flag as READY before msg is actually updated.

Caching - The CPU may cache the value of flag in a register for performance. So the writer thread may update flag, but the reader thread continues to see the old cached value.

By using atomic operations, you disable these optimizations and ensure that:

Instructions are executed in program order
Writes to shared memory are visible to other threads immediately.
So in summary, for simple examples like this, omitting atomics may work. But for robust, portable code that works on all platforms, you should use atomic operations when accessing shared variables from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I think the concept of "memory consistency model" is involved in your answer. This makes sense for me.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad my explanation made sense.